# issues with jmeter concurency testing

Tags: stress-testing, jmeter

I'm doing stress test on my web server, using 8 different clients in jmeter:

- 3 of them are on SunOS 5
- 3 of them are on SunOS 5 but in virutalbox
- 2 of them are on linux

If I do a test only using clients which are on SunOS machines I receive best result (my web server can service ~1300 req/sec). If I make a test using all client machines, my result is ~half (600-800 req/sec) of result which I get using only 3 SunOS machines.

Can someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be network congestion or network overhead. Your jmeter machines not only connect to the client, but they are also sending back results to the jmeter master machine. More jmeter machines does not always mean more load on your application.

Try to find httpd timing logs, and try to find network througput for all machines and see what you come up with. Hope this helps. Cheers!